# PEAR Mail_Queue sending duplicate emails

Tags: php, pear, mail-queue

Here are a couple of questions:

Is `mail_queue->put` supposed to insert a message twice in the database? The only differences are the `time_to_send` value and the `user_id`.

This is what I get for a single message for one user:

```
1. user_id = 1, time_to_send = 2009-02-10 14:02:02
2. user_id = -1, time_to_send = 2009-02-10 14:00:02
```

The first one is what I would expect, but what purpose does the second one serve?

If I send the queue, the message will arrive twice. If I delete the one with the negative `user_id`, only a single mail gets sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the program line-by-line and sure enough, there was an uncommented example for the `put` function.

Answer (score 1):

> function put($from, $to, $hdrs, $body, $sec_to_send=0, $delete_after_send=true, $id_user=MAILQUEUE_SYSTEM)

Do you pass the parameter $id_user or is it the default value?

Comment: I tried both. In this case I passed 1 as $id_user, but even with the defaults I get duplicates. The default seems to be 0, and the duplicate still has the id of -1.